# Modeling multiple benchmark results with few shared pairs

Tags: regression, modeling, paired-data

I have benchmark results for just over 1,000 computers systems, run in the 1960s, 70s and 80s.

The catch is that there are five different benchmarks.  The relationship between different benchmark results is not always linear (it's close to square root in a few cases, the log transformed data is linear), and only a handful of systems (around 20'ish) have results across pairs of benchmarks.

I want to compare the relative performance across all computers.

A simplistic approach would be to build regression models for each pair of benchmarks.  These models could be used to calculate the relative performance of computer *A* against computer *B* by finding a sequence of models connecting *A* and *B*.

I have thought of using seemingly unrelated regression (using R's systemfit package).  One benchmark is chosen as the base, and a regression model is built for mapping every other benchmark to this base (the relationship of the log transformed results is linear).

Is it possible to build a model that does not require going via an intermediate step of pairs of regression models?

The plot below shows the log transformed results from four computer benchmarks in pairwise comparison.

[image: Results from multiple computer benchmarks in pairwise comparison]